# A thin rod is standing on a smooth surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, rotation

A uniform thin rod of mass m and length l is standing on a horizontal surface. A slight disturbance causes the lower end of the rod to start falling. find the velocity of the centre of mass of the rod at the instant when it makes an angle (theta)?

i believe that the centre of mass will move vertically downwards as there is no external force acting on it... but how does one decide the instantaneous axis of rotation for this motion?

Answer (score 1):

Find two points on the rod where the instantaneous direction of motion is known (one of these points is the centre of mass). Draw a line through each point perpendicular to its instantaneous direction of motion. The instantaneous axis of rotation will go through the point where these lines meet.

Comment: Thanks a ton, found the answer..